# Other divs moving when list appears as dropdown in navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to CSS so please forgive me for any shortcomings from my side.

I am working on a website and have made a navbar in which I have a few divs.
Some of the divs contain a list which kind of drops down when I hover of them. 
The problem is that this makes the div itself increase in width and that makes other divs around it move around.
I have observed that the width that it increases to is the width of the lengthiest element in the list.
I have no idea what is causing it and have tried playing with the position but nothing seems to work.
I would like to just stop the moving around of the above divs so that it doesn't look weird.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div  class="header" id="banner"></div>
<div class="header" id="navbar">
    <div class="nb_item">HOME</div>
    <div class="nb_item">ABOUT US
        <ul id="abtus_menu">
            <li>LA MARTINIERE COLLEGE, LUCKNOW</li>
            <li>LA MARTINIERE MODEL UNITED NATIONS</li>
            <li>SECRETARIAT</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    <div class="nb_item">REGISTER
        <ul id="rgstr_menu">
            <li>INDIVIDUAL</li>
            <li>DELEGATION</li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nb_item">COMMITTEES
        <ul id="comt_menu">
            <li>COMMITTEE 1</li>
            <li>COMMITTEE 2</li>
            <li>COMMITTEE 3</li>
            <li>COMMITTEE 4</li>
            <li>COMMITTEE 5</li>
            <li>COMMITTEE 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nb_item">RESOURCES</div>
    <div class="nb_item">EVENTS
        <ul id="evnt_menu">
            <li>KEYNOTE SPEAKERS</li>
            <li>SOCIALS</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nb_item">SPONSORS</div>
    <div class="nb_item">CONTACT US</div>
```

CSS:

```
.html
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.header
{
    width: 80%;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
    display:flex;   
}

#banner
{
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

#navbar
{

    background-color: #70A5DA;
    height: 28px;   
}

.menu
{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.nb_item
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    padding:0px 10px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:28px;
}

.nb_item:hover
{
    color: #DDDDDD;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#abtus_menu li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;

}
.nb_item:hover #abtus_menu li
{
    display:block;
    color: #DDDDDD;
}

#comt_menu li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
}

.nb_item:hover #comt_menu li
{
    display:block;
}



#rgstr_menu li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
}

.nb_item:hover #rgstr_menu li
{
    display:block;
}

#evnt_menu li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:none;
}

.nb_item:hover #evnt_menu li
{
    display:block;
}


.menu li
{
    display:inline;
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntxo9uyj/) (Zoom out to 50% if there are problems viewing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the DIVs are part of the document flow, hence when they are displayed, everything pushes out.
What you need to do is to use position absolute on them like this:

```
.nb_item {position: relative}
/* This allows it's child absolute elements to adhere to their parents position (.nb_item) */
```

And then:

```
.nb_item ul {position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0}
/* This absolutely positions the child (drop down menu) element so it's taken out of the document flow, hence not affecting positions of other elements */
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Absolutely positioned elements should have a width defined, otherwise they will take on the width of the widest non-breaking word. Try this:

```
.nb_item ul {width: 200px; border: 1px solid #000}
.nb_item ul li {text-align: left}
.nb_item ul li a {padding: 10px}
```

Comment: That worked but now the items that come on hover are coming to the right of all the headings. I want them right under and that each of then should have text in one line no matter the width. What is happening is all are coming one under othr but the text is crammed in different lines. Image link : http://i.imgur.com/lOYCc30.png

Comment: That's because the text is centered so it looks like it's off to the right. Add this in: `.nb_item ul li {text-align: left}`

Comment: Add text-align: left and it shows in multiple lines because it tries to fit inside the .nb_item which is the containing element for it because of position relative on that.

Comment: @thePav I have encountered another problem, when my cursor is even near the div these appear individually. Go to the JSFiddle and see for yourself. Bring cursor near or to the right of where the drop down should be and it'll appear. http://jsfiddle.net/2pv12ej1/

Comment: Use `display: none` on default and `display: block` on hover like this: `.nb_item ul {display: none}` for default state and `.nb_item:hover ul {display: block}` for hover state.

Answer (score 2):

```
    .nb_item {
        position: relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:auto;
        padding:0px 10px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        margin:auto;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:28px;
    }
    ul {
        padding-left: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
    .nb_item ul li {
        text-align: left;
    }
```

Change the position from absolute to fixed for ul and then you no need to assign any width to any element.